# Is there a Russian edition of Khrushchev Remembers?

Tags: russian-language, nikita-khrushchev, khrushchev-remembers

I looked for a while but cannot find if there is an original publication of Khrushchev's memoirs in Russian. I'd much rather read it in its original language since I speak Russian, but I can only find English versions.

Comment: To the close-voter: questions about the availability of translations have been [deemed on-topic](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/209/17) on meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can easily buy it at Russia, for example:

http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/137961608/

http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/137961612/

Digital versions also exist and are easily findable.

Comment: i found an even more complete list here: https://www.e-reading.club/bookbyauthor.php?author=16758
before seeing your links, i didnt even know what the russian name of the publications were, as all sites directed me to an english reference